# SSRS not available on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, ssrs-2012

I am trying to open my SSRS project (created using VS 2012) on Visual Studio 2015, and it says that such projects are not supported. What is one supposed to do to keep working on SSRS reports?

Comment: Do you have installed `SSDT`? Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not add the BI project types. They haven't released the VS 2015 extensions yet (although, I believe the SSIS one is available as a CTP). Look at the preview for the newest version of SSMS to get this integration.

Comment: Is it imperative you use Visual Studio? - I switched to the much simpler Report Builder 3 earlier this year, and its much simpler and more reliable.  It has all the functionality of VS.